# Encode string representation of integer to base64 in Python 3

Tags: python, string, int, base64, encode

I'm trying to encode an int in to base64, i'm doing that:

```
foo = 1
base64.b64encode(bytes(foo))
```

**expected output:** `'MQ=='`

**given output:** `b'AA=='`

what i'm doing wrong?

Edit: in Python 2.7.2 works correctly

Comment: Hmm... what version of Python are you using?  When I do base64.b64encode(bytes(1)) or foo=1;base64.b64encode(bytes(foo)) I'm getting 'MQ=='.  Also, where are you running this on?

Comment: When I run your code, I have the expected output. Did you redefine foo somewhere else? try base64.b64encode(b'1')

Comment: i'm using Python 3.3.2

Comment: in Python 2.7.2 is working :/

Comment: Confirmed: in Python 3.1.2 it prints `b'AA=='`. The problem is not `b64encode`, it is `bytes()`. In Python3, `bytes(1)` returns `b'00'`.

Comment: in python3 bytes() works as cast?

Comment: @Foon, this uses b'string', how can i do this with a variable?

Comment: NOTE: This is definitely not a duplicate.   And none of the answers below are correct.   See comments.

Comment: @ErikAronesty Thanks to your comments, I have written a new question and answer: [Python: Efficiently encode large integer as base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152762/python-efficiently-encode-large-integer-as-base64/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
foo = 1
base64.b64encode(bytes([foo]))
```

or

```
foo = 1
base64.b64encode(bytes(str(foo), 'ascii'))
# Or, roughly equivalently:
base64.b64encode(str(foo).encode('ascii'))
```

The first example encodes the 1-byte integer `1`. The 2nd example encodes the 1-byte character string `'1'`.

Comment: this is returning `AQ==` instead of `MQ==`

Comment: The 2nd example returns `MQ==`.

Comment: For others who want to encode integers but don't have expected output: This works, but the encoded string can be much longer than needed. That's because by converting numbers to strings, you're only using a tiny fraction of the input space, but b64encode doesn't know about that (e.g.it doesn't know there'll never be a letter). I think it's better to use the `struct` module to do `b64encode(pack('<Q', foo).rstrip('\x00') or '\x00').rstrip('=')` which will give you a much shorter encoded string for big integers.

Comment: This is the actual answer:

 `base64.b64encode(i.to_bytes(ceil(i.bit_length()/8),'big'))`

Question should NOT be closed.

Comment: @ErikAronesty's answer was the correct one for me. People online don't seem to understand the concept of string -> int (bytes) -> base64 string to produce the shortest string. The answer to the numeric value `29270` should be the base64 string `clY=`. String `"29270"` -> Integer `29270` -> Binary Data `111001001010110` -> Base64 `clY=`. Integer Value `1` -> Binary Data `1` -> Base64 `AQ==`. Really it's `string` -> `base 10` -> `base 64`.

Comment: @ErikAronesty how would that short approach work if negative numbers are possible?

Comment: @luckydonald  use this command for signed, but be aware that converting back needs a similar flag: base64.b64encode(i.to_bytes(ceil(i.bit_length()/8),'big',signed=True))

Comment: `base64.b64encode(i.to_bytes((i.bit_length()+8)//8,'big',signed=True))` to get signed converted correctly.  and `int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(z),'big',signed=True)` to decode signed   ( i switched to using +8 ... //8 instead of ceil... one less library, and it gives you the extra bit you need for the sign)

Comment: @luckydonald I have written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54152763/832230) formalizing the comments by Erik; it addresses negative numbers too.

Answer (score 16):

If you initialize bytes(N) with an integer N, it will give you bytes of length N initialized with null bytes:

```
>>> bytes(10)
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

what you want is the string "1"; so encode it to bytes with:

```
>>> "1".encode()
b'1'
```

now, base64 will give you `b'MQ=='`:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64encode("1".encode())
b'MQ=='
```

Comment: base64.b64encode(i.to_bytes(ceil(i.bit_length()/8),'big'))