# Behavior change of bytes from py2 to py3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, casting

I got curious after the discussion taking place on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616657/how-to-encode-integer-in-to-base64-string-in-python-3). It appears that the behavior of `bytes()` has changed in python3. In [the docs for py3](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html) it is now listed as a built-in function that behaves the same as `bytearray()` except for the result being immutable. It doesn't appear in the same place in py2 docs.

In digging thru the docs for a while I couldn't really find anything detailing what's changed from 2 to 3, but it looks like something definitely has. What's the difference and why was it changed?

From the linked question in the comments someone remarked with respect to py3

> bytes(1) returns b'00'

but in 2.7.5

```
>>> bytes(1)
'1'
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Comment: in python2, `bytes` _is_ `str`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python 3 `bytes` constructor takes an optional `int` parameter specifying the number of bytes to output. All bytes are initialized to 0 (`\x00`) with that constructor, so `bytes(1) == b'\x00'`.

The Python 2 `bytes` constructor is identical to `str`, and therefore just stringizes its argument:

```
Python 2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> bytes is str
True
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `bytes()` in Python 2 if it is synonymous with `str()`?

Comment: @Brian: I guess it is for some measure of similarity with Python3, but clearly it causes confusion...