# How can I encode an integer into Base64 in Jython for Open Refine?

Tags: python, base64, jython, openrefine

I want to encode an integer into a short string using Base64 and return the value to Open Refine (Google Refine).

I found examples but they always give me an error.

```
import base64
foo = base64.b64encode('1')
return foo
```

works returning "MQ=="

But I want to encode the integer 1. The folowing code gives me an error.

```
import base64
foo = base64.b64encode(bytes([1]))
return foo
```

The example I found is here: [How to encode integer in to base64 string in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616657/how-to-encode-integer-in-to-base64-string-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use binary data in string in form of `\xx` where `xx` is hexadecimal representation of byte.

With Python2 (including Jython2) try:

```
foo = base64.b64encode('\01')
```

for Python3:

```
foo = base64.b64encode(b'\01')
```

My result: `AQ==`

Comment: Thanks @Michał. I wasn't familiar with Python byte types.